# compile spring boot application by native-image

Tags: java, spring, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to compile spring boot application by native-image executing following command
native-image --no-fallback -jar rest.jar
all compiling good, but at run time I see an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.<init>(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:52)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.<init>(JarLauncher.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1581)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1476)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1483)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1288)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1251)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:732)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:849)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:247)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:348)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:319)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:285)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.AbstractJarFile.<init>(AbstractJarFile.java:39)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.<init>(JarFileArchive.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.<init>(JarFileArchive.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.createArchive(Launcher.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.<init>(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:48)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you compile binary from fat jar by native-image it gets Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher from manifest and trying to make executable binary whith entry point JarLauncher. Then you run compiled binary it try to open himself for reading as zip archive and throwing a ZipException. Try this https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/16/spring-tips-the-graalvm-native-image-builder-feature